# Scapy: bind layers with PacketField

Tags: python, scapy

I have a packet class (called `Layer1()`) made up of two PacketField (`header1` and `header2`).
I would like to configure a binding relation so that when joining with an upper layer (IP in this example), it automatically sets the `typeNext` field of the `header2` PacketField.

I tried  with `bind_layers(Layer1, IP, header2=Header2(typeNext=9))`

But this doesn't work. Maybe because the biding doesn't do a deep copy?

Thanks by advance for your help!

```
class Header1(Packet):
    name = "Content"
    fields_desc = [
        XByteField("foo1", 1),
        XByteField("bar1", 1)]

class Header2(Packet):
    name = "Content"
    fields_desc = [
        XByteField("foo2", 2),
        XByteField("typeNext", 2)]

class Layer1(Packet):
    name = "headerPacket"
    fields_desc = [
        PacketField("header1", Header1(), Header1),
        PacketField("header2", Header2(), Header2)]

bind_layers(Layer1, IP, header2=Header2(typeNext=9))

P=Layer1()/IP()
P.show()
```

This gives me:

```
###[ headerPacket ]### 
  \header1   \
   |###[ Content ]### 
   |  foo1      = 0x1
   |  bar1      = 0x1
  \header2   \
   |###[ Content ]### 
   |  foo2      = 0x2
   |  typeNext  = 0x2
###[ IP ]### 
     version   = 4
     ihl       = None
     tos       = 0x0
     len       = None
     id        = 1
     flags     = 
     frag      = 0
     ttl       = 64
     proto     = hopopt
     chksum    = None
     src       = 127.0.0.1
     dst       = 127.0.0.1
     \options   \
```

While I would expect (`typeNext=9`):

```
###[ headerPacket ]### 
  \header1   \
   |###[ Content ]### 
   |  foo1      = 0x1
   |  bar1      = 0x1
  \header2   \
   |###[ Content ]### 
   |  foo2      = 0x2
   |  typeNext  = 0x9
###[ IP ]### 
     version   = 4
     ihl       = None
     tos       = 0x0
     len       = None
     id        = 1
     flags     = 
     frag      = 0
     ttl       = 64
     proto     = hopopt
     chksum    = None
     src       = 127.0.0.1
     dst       = 127.0.0.1
     \options   \
```